# Explain what this Jquery code is saying please

Tags: jquery

Ok so I'm going to use this code to create a sticky nav when scrolled. But I would like to fulling understand what it means before I implement it. Ok so what I need to know is why on line 3 is stickyNav function started with a variable? is this because it is retuning an integer value? Also why is the StickyNav(); function called twice on line 11 and 13? Heres the link to the tutorial     http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-sticky-position/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var stickyNavTop = $('.nav').offset().top;

var stickyNav = function(){
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) { 
$('.nav').addClass('sticky');
} else {
$('.nav').removeClass('sticky'); 
}
};

stickyNav();

$(window).scroll(function() {
stickyNav();
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made some inline comments to explain the code.
Hope that will help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // The offset in px from top (y=0) to .nav element
  var stickyNavTop = $('.nav').offset().top;

  // stickyNav is a function()
  var stickyNav = function() {
    // scrollTop is the offset in px where 
    // the browser window is currently scrolled to
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    // test if the user scrolled over the navigation
    if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {
      // add class
      $('.nav').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
      // remove class
      $('.nav').removeClass('sticky');
    }
  };

  // call when the body is loaded first time
  stickyNav();

  // register on scroll event
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    // call the function when the user scrolls
    stickyNav();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 3 is simply an alternative way of saying

```
function stickyNav() {
```

In line 11 you set up the proper class for the nav at initial document load. In line 13, the class is refreshed whenever the user scrolls the document.

Answer (score 0):

> why on line 3 is stickyNav function started with a variable?

In javascript, functions are first class citizens and what you have on line 3 is a variable named stickyNav that holds the function defined there.

A variable defined with "var" inside of another outer function scope is a private variable accessible from the inside of the outer function and the functions defined in that same scope. Also called a closure.

> is this because it is returning an integer value?

No, it is a function that you can call

> Also why is the StickyNav(); function called twice on line 11 and 13?

The first one initiate it, useful if your sticky navigator is already off the screen. Then it is called everytime the window is scrolled.